# Is it possible to inherit from multiple abstract classes in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Is it possible to **inherit from multiple abstract classes** in Java?

Comment: if you mean a parent and grandparent class can be abstract then yes... the multiple inheritance means another thing in oop...

Comment: No, you can only inherit from **one** class in Java. See the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) for details

Comment: You can implement multiple interfaces, but you can only inherit from one class, which in turn can inherit from one class, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in a some way but only with transitive inheriting as Java doesn't support explicit multiple inheritance for classes.

You can indeed have a class `X` that derives from an abstract class `Y` that derives itself from an abstract class `Z`.

```
public class X extends Y {...}
public abstract class Y extends Z{...}
public abstract class Z {...}
```

`Collection` classes are a good example of that :

For example, the concrete class `ArrayList` extends the abstract class `AbstractList` that extends the abstract class `AbstractCollection`